# Is HTML5 validation possible with the Web Plugin for SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

Does the Web Plugin for SonarQube allow HTML5 validation? Has anyone tried that?

I've read the plugin's documentation, and it mentions JSPs and HTMLs, but I need to know if it supports the new HTML5 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested html5 validation with sonarqube 3.7 and the last web Plugin, and it works fine. There are a few specific rules for html5 tags. It's a good base to start working, and you can add more rules with regular expressions.